# About first order logic exercise

Tags: logic

Prove that the sentence
∀x∃yP(x, y)∧∀x∀y(P(x, y) ⇒ ¬P(y, x))∧∀x∀y∀z(P(x, y) ⇒ (P(y, z) ⇒ P(x, z)))
is false in all finite structures but is true in a certain infinite structure (P is
a binary predicate, x, y, z are variables).
I don't know how to start, first a predicate would be true or false, then do I have to consider all of the situations and see if its true or not this formula? I can see with example of specific predicates but not with this abstraction. And for the infinite question I dont have any idea.

Answer (score 2):

For an infinite model, interpret $P(x,y)$ as $x$ is smaller than $y$ on the domain of the natural numbers.

To see that there is no finite model, notice that the predicate needs to be interpreted as a relation that is asymmetric and transitive by the second and third conjunct, so it sets up an order (a strict partial order, to be exact) on the elements of the domain, meaning that it should be possible to 'line up' all objects from left to right such that anytime two objects stand in the relation $P$ to each other, the first element is to the left of the second. So, if there are only finitely many elements, then there will be a 'right-most' element, and this element cannot stand in any relationship to anything else, since it is not to the 'left' of anything else. So the first conjunct (which says that for every element there is always an element to the 'right' of it) is then automatically not true. You can now also understand how with infinitely many objects in such an order (e.g smaller than for natural numbers) all three conjuncts, and hence the statement as a whole, is satisfied.